# Integrating D3 charts in Meteor

Tags: d3.js, meteor

I already have previously made charts with D3.js that I'm trying to transfer into Meteor, but it's not working at the moment.

I placed the D3 code in the helper and then render it in HTML via the `{{helper}}` syntax. I tried placing it in the onRendered and onCreated spaces, but not sure how that would be transferred to the HTML itself.

Any help on how to render these graphs on Meteor would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve], and define what you mean by _it's not working_.

Comment: did you try using their official package? or you just placed the .js into your project. 
`https://atmospherejs.com/d3js/d3`

Comment: Sorry. I'm using the official D3 package for meteor. The code is over 300 lines long. That's why I didn't post it. Simply, the chart doesn't show on the template. There are no errors in the console.

Answer (score -2):

I use c3 package instead of d3.   It's easier.